# How to modify multiple elements, one after the other

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an image fader. I have it so that it fades the image (or in this case div with a background color) selected by the `getElementById` method, but I'm wondering how I can modify the JavaScript code to select all div elements and fade out, one after the other.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("one");

function fade(){
  if (!c.style.opacity){
    c.style.opacity = 1;
  };
  
  var interval = setInterval (fadeout, 200);
  
  function fadeout(){
    c.style.opacity -= .05;
    
    if (c.style.opacity <= 0){
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  };
};

fade();
```

```css
#container{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}

.inner{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#one{
  background-color: rgb(100,100,100);
}

#two{
  background-color: rgb(0,160,230);
}

#three {
  background-color: rgb(0,255,130);
}

#four{
  background-color: rgb(255,130,255);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="inner" id="one"></div>
  <div class="inner" id="two"></div>
  <div class="inner" id="three"></div>
  <div class="inner" id="four"></div>
</div>
```

I also need a way (possibly making the function recursive) to keep going from four back to one, and I will not use jQuery for this.

Comment: Didn't understand the title, didn't find a question. What is it you are trying to accomplish and what is the problem you are having.

Comment: `function fade(c){ /*code unchanged*/ }`. `fade(document.getElementById("one")); fade(document.getElementById("two"));`.

Comment: im not sure I understand this, can you elaborate?

Comment: I think he means he wishes to chain the fade event on 4 different divs. This can be accomplished using a callback or promise.

Comment: @IshanSharma chaining is only good when the duration of what you're doing is unknown. But it's a tradeoff for the inability to animate two  or more items in the same time at short intervals (rapid fire a.k.a staggering). The proper way to stagger animations is by using timeOuts. You can still match the animation duration with the stagger step if you want them to look chained. But maybe I'm wrong, and the OP wants chaining (the particular case) not staggering (the general case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```js
var interval = 4000,
  collection = document.querySelectorAll('#container>.inner');

for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      collection[collection.length - i - 1].style.opacity = 0;
    }, i * interval);
  })(i)
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: opacity 4s linear;
}

#one {
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

#two {
  background-color: rgb(0, 160, 230);
}

#three {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 130);
}

#four {
  background-color: rgb(255, 130, 255);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="inner" id="one"></div>
  <div class="inner" id="two"></div>
  <div class="inner" id="three"></div>
  <div class="inner" id="four"></div>
</div>
```

To give it a more *natural* feel (impression of intent, gesture, livelyness) you need to change `linear` to the easing of your choice in CSS:

```js
var interval = 4000,
  collection = document.querySelectorAll('#container>.inner');

for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      collection[collection.length - i - 1].style.opacity = 0;
    }, i * interval);
  })(i)
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: opacity 4s cubic-bezier(.6, 0, .3, 1);
}

#one {
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

#two {
  background-color: rgb(0, 160, 230);
}

#three {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 130);
}

#four {
  background-color: rgb(255, 130, 255);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="inner" id="one"></div>
  <div class="inner" id="two"></div>
  <div class="inner" id="three"></div>
  <div class="inner" id="four"></div>
</div>
```

**Principle:** whenever you want to stagger animations (repeat exact same animation on a collection of elements), chaining the start of one animation upon the end of the previous is, to say the least, improper. You are limiting yourself to always having to wait for one animation to end in order to start the next. But you normally want this behavior when the duration of an action is unknown at the time you are executing the script. Here, it's the same duration so chaining is only a useless limitation.

Instead, use `setTimeout()` on the collection and you will end up having the option of animating multiple elements at any given moment and having better (separated) controls over animation details (duration, timing function and stagger step).

Another big problem with your approach is you're making 20 changes for each element, instead of only one. CSS animations give you control over `animation-duration`, `animation-timing-function` (very important when animating movement) and `animation-delay` (not used here). Besides, it's smoother and lighter on the browser.

I'll exemplify below, by animating movement instead of opacity:

```js
// only set the stagger step and the collection in js
// set animation duration and easing in CSS for best results

var interval = 63, // stagger step
  collection = document.querySelectorAll('div');
// in your case, use document.querySelectorAll('#container>.inner');

for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      collection[i].style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
    }, i * interval);
  })(i)
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-top: 1px;
  min-height: .5rem;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* here it is: duration 300ms, and transition
   * I've put in cubic, as it's good for staggered movement
   * it looks natural. For opacity it doesn't matter
   * it can be linear, ease-out, anything.
   */
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, .1, 1);
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
```

---

Initial answer, before noticing a jQuery free solution is required:

```js
// only set the stagger step and the collection in js
// set animation duration and easing in CSS for best results

var interval = 42, // stagger step
  collection = $('div'); // in your case, use $('#container>.inner');

collection.each(function(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    collection.eq(i).css('opacity', 0);
  }, i * interval);
})
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-top: 1px;
  min-height: .5rem;
  /* here it is: duration 300ms, and transition
   * I've put in cubic, as it's good for staggered movement
   * it looks natural. For opacity it doesn't matter
   * it can be linear, ease-out, anything.
   */
  transition: opacity 300ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>    <div></div>    <div></div>
<div></div>
```

---

**End note:** This answer did not even touch the new (and promising) way to animate: [Web Animations Api](https://w3c.github.io/web-animations/), because it's still experimental tech.
WAA animates using chaining but provides methods to cancel animation requests. It works in all major browsers and can be used with *polyfill* in older browsers.
It will probably gain huge popularity once Android browsers will support it. Until then, the best way to animate is using `CSS` animations and transitions which, even if not declaratively, also support canceling a request: you just change the property and it automatically starts a new animation on the same property from the current state, canceling the old one. The only CSS current limitation is that it won't calculate the new duration based on how much of the old one has been completed, which is possible in WAA.
What WAA does is unifying CSS animations, CSS transitions and SVG animations under one, common set of specs and will provide a unified set of methods for controlling animations.

Comment: @Ibu [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) + setTimeout() + [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) + [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/). That's pretty much it. You set the collection, stagger step and off you go. Stagger animations in jQuery, by yours truly. If you want it smooth, you trigger it on an animatable prop, like `opacity`. But it can be `transforms` for staggering movement intros or outtros. But really, I'd love to know why you down-voted.

Comment: @Ibu For each item in the collection, I set a timeout function with a delay of the interval multiplied by current index, on the nth (`eq(i)`) item of the colection. I don't know what else to explain. For me it is pretty obvious. Besides, you haven't answered my question.

Comment: @Ibu When I give answers on [so], I prefer to provide answers that would work for more than just the OP case. So I made a more general script in which OP can place params, according to my comment and it will (hopefully) help future users, too. Look at some of my other answers to get a general idea of my approach. Take care.

Comment: Maybe you did not understand my question. I asked to explain for the very reason you are writing all these comments. All I was suggesting, is that you explain what you did in your answer (inside the answer, not in comments.) This way, your goal of providing a general answer that can help anyone in the future will be met.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I just noticed the OP said they don't want jQuery. I'll just rewrite using vanilla. I was buffled by the downvotes.

Comment: @Ibu I hope you're happy now. Cheers! And ***thank you***. I wasn't really paying attention.

Comment: thanks, that's a great help, although I don't fully understand it. how does it fade out each div when the only decrement is from 1 opacity to 0 opacity in the js? I noticed the transition in the css, does that control the fade? I doubt it because its not mentioned in the js script

Comment: The answer to that question was originally a code comment and it didn't make it into the final version. But you'll find it in the other examples. You want to control the details of the animation (duration, easing and delay) from CSS. It can be done in `javascript` too. But I did it from `CSS`. I'm only setting the duration between subsequent starts (stagger step) in js.

Comment: @busso the only difference between first and second code samples is one line in `CSS`. I changed `linear` to `cubic-bezier(.6,0,.3,1)`. That line is what controls one single animation. Having a duration of `4s` and setting stagger step to also `4s = 4000` (in `js`) makes them seem *"chained"*.

Comment: I still don't understand, what controls the reduction of opacity, the css or the js?

Comment: `transition: opacity 4s linear;` If it's `1` and you set it to `0`, it will do so over 4 seconds, linearily. Why don't you test with a red div over a white background in a [`jsFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/fLfu1svu/)?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Good job!

Comment: If you tell users to use the better of either plain javascript or jQuery in a given case, you help them more than saying, "look so bad javascript is, where you need a closure for it work" (which by the way it doesn't) and "how good jQuery is, that magically does it". Why should a user take the unnecessary workload of using jQuery when a simple plain "for...loop" does it faster, and with `let` won't need a closure? ... And note, I like your answers most of the time, and the effort you put in writing them.

Comment: @LG, since I've written this answer (almost two years ago) I've given up on advising people to use or not a particular library or framework. Also, I feel my understanding of JavaScript in general and differences between versions in particular has improved, point being I'd probably write my answer differently today. As a result, I'll remove that part.