# JQuery and CSS relationship - .fadeOut() and classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

continuing my self-teaching of the online programming languages today and could use a little more help from you experts.

I have 2 questions that I can't seem to find a definitive answer on in the WWW.

1. JS - when using `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`, do these relate directly to CSS elements? I.e. does it scale the opacity to 0 <> 1 respectively? Or is it completely separate and handled purely by the JS?
2. CSS - when adding and removing classes using `addClass()` and `removeClass()`, and even `toggleClass()`, how do these get "displayed" as such, like what is the logical format for this? For example, if I have this:

```js
 <div id="me" class="thisisset">
```

and wanted to use:

```
$("#me").addClass("token");
```

does this then become, in theory:

```
 <div id="me" class="thisisset token">
```

With both `.thisisset` and `.token` applied separately, or do they amalgamate into some kind of super class?

Comment: On 2-: adding classes to element collections using a `setTimeout()` function is currently regarded as most reliable cross-browser method to create stagger animations. Basic principle: have two states of the element, one *with* the class, one *without* it. They should have different values in `animatable` properties and `transition` defined for all/each. Once you apply the class, `CSS` will perform the transition according to `transition-timing-function`, `transition-duration` and `transition-delay` properties. I've written more [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42261120/1891677)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you [check the source](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.fadeOut) you can see it uses the `animate()` method internally, which runs solely in JS via a queue pattern.

   It's for this reason that it's generally considered much better practice to animate using CSS instead, where possible, as it is hardware accelerated and performs *much, much* better.
2. The browser will use both rules as set in the CSS. If there's a conflict in the settings, eg. both set `color`, then the most specific rule will be used. Here's an example:

```css
#container .foo { color: red; }
.bar { color: blue; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="foo bar">This will be red as the .foo rule is more specific</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, but on the other hand, `.animate()` performs quite well with `opacity` and `transform`s. (They're the only two properties one should ever animate with `.animate()`). But even for those, `.velocity()` is better.

Comment: CSS will still always be faster though. Also, you can animate `opacity` fine in CSS alone, no need for JS there.

Comment: Agreed, but sometimes one needs to queue up multiple animations that should chain/trigger each other. `CSS`s not really an option there, is it? Not to mention user interaction :).

Comment: Yep it is, you can use `@keyframes`

Comment: `CSS` is not currently able to calculate how much of an animation has been performed and perform another one based on this info. When doing complex animations, that's sometimes needed. I always use `CSS` animations as much as I can, but I'm against preaching it solves all problems/use-cases, because it does not. Regards,

Comment: Perfect, thank you all for your answers. Without these building-block basics I'd never have been able to truly understand how it works for more complicated coding later. Thank you all for your time, you guys really are the best teachers!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu that's true, and IMO is the only case where `animate()` should be used. Although if you can get the timings right, `@keyframes` could still work.

Comment: @RichardGoodman no problem, glad to help. Also, Re. #2 you can check the styles applied to an element in the console. If you right click the element, then 'Inspect' you'll see the CSS rules on the right hand side.

Comment: did not know that! oh wow that will make life so much easier! thank you!!