# CSS Transition from display none to display block and vice versa

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-transitions, css-animations

I know this question has probably been asked million times here in SO, but Ive tried most of the solution, I just dont know why it dont work for me.

So I have a dropdown with `display` initially targeted to `none`. When I click on it, it shows nice transition. (So far so good). But when I click on it again to go hide the dropdown, it hides immediately, but I dont want that. I want to hide with similar transition that was assigned to show. Here is my code for CSS:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0 0;
  display: none;
  -webkit-animation: slide-down .3s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: slide-down .3s ease-out;
}

.table-dropdown-open {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: slide-down .3s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: slide-down .3s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide-down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

This is not a dupliacte because Im trying to give transition from `block` to 
`none`. Not from `none` to `block`

Comment: Transitions or Animations in CSS won't work on `display: none` / `display: block`. Use `opacity: 0` / `opacity: 1` OR `visibility` property.

Comment: I thought it would work as you can integrate from block to none. Are you sure it wont work from none to block? @MuhammadUsman

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transitions on the display: property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

Comment: @DingDong Can you please give an example where the `display` property is gradually transitioned from `block` to `none`, please? I never thought it was possible. Really appreciate the effort, thank you.

Comment: I think you may be right. It is highly unlikely. But how do I achieve from the transition effect by hiding dropdown? @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: You `display` it at all times and `transition` an `animatable` property. Such as `opacity`, from `0` to `1`. You can also play with `transform`. In effect, `transform` and `opacity` are the only 2 properties you should ever animate, as they don't require `DOM` to repaint anything other than the element you're animating, thus not hitting browser performance, even when you're animating a considerable amount of elements simultaneously.

Comment: Wow, great answer. Please write an anwer below, aso that I can accept yours. You have explained performanc of browser. +1 for that @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: Added it as an answer, with a few extra details you should pay attention to. Happy coding!

Comment: To add onto Mohammad Usman's and Andrei Gheorghiu comments, you can obtain the effects of display none by using 'position: absolute' and 'visibility: hidden'. This avoids the problems associated with elements not transitioning with 'display: none'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`display` your element at all times and only `transition` any `animatable` property. In your case, `opacity` looks like a good candidate, though playing with `transform` might also give you the desired result. Simple example:

```
any {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.5,0,.3,1);
}
any.animated {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

In effect, `opacity` and `transform` should be the only two properties you should animate, as they don't require `DOM` repaint on anything other than the animated element, thus not hitting browser performance, even when you're animating a considerable amount of elements simultaneously.

Please note that, even if not painted, your elements are, in effect, in the place where they would be when not `transform`ed at all. So you might want to give them `pointer-events:none` when they are in the *"invisible"* state and `pointer-events:all` when they are in *"visible"* state, so they don't catch any pointer events while not visible.

---

Considering your example, I've given you two animation examples (with keyframes and without). Remember you need to [`prefix your code`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). For full browser compatibility, use `> 0%` in settings (the small box at the bottom).

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  var dm = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');
  dm.classList.remove('hide-menu');
}, 300);
```

```css
/* simple animation example, on parent. No keyframes. */
.dropdown-menu.hide-menu {
  opacity: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  position: relative;
  animation: delay-overflow .3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
.dropdown-menu:hover {
  animation: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* animation example with keyframes, on child */

.dropdown-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  animation: slide-up .3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

.drowdown-menu.hide-menu ul {
  animation-duration: 0s;
}
.dropdown-menu:hover ul {
  animation: slide-down .3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes slide-down {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-up {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
}
@keyframes delay-overflow {
  0% {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  99% {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  100% {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu hide-menu">
  <span>Menu</span>
  <ul>
    <li>A menu item</li>
    <li>Another menu item</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>And so on...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Note:** A very handy trick with `animation` property is that it allows you to delay applying any property, even non-animatable ones from applying for the desired amount of time. I'm using this trick to delay `overflow:hidden` applying on the parent (and `overflow` is not animatable) so the animation of the child - which happens outside the bounds of the parent - is visible until the end. After it finishes, the `overflow:hidden` applies and it no longer catches mouse events outside the menu opener.

Comment: If you're interested in animating with regard to browser performance and triggering stagger animations on collections of elements, I have recently answered [`another question`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42261120/1891677) with a few more details on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

it is just simple logic, you currently have styled you slide down but you have not styled the cancellation of the div. You must first have a closed state which i believe in your case is .dropdown-menu

```
.dropdown-menu {
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

or just use

```
.dropdown-menu {
    transition: margin 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
}
```

If this does not work,