# Not a crazy fast sub menu reveal with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, navigation

I've got a vertical mobile menu, where I have a sub menu. I'm using jQuery to reveal it, and a function .toggleClass. The problem that it happens instantly, and tremendously fast. Is there a way to do it in a more subtle way (apply a transition of some kind)?

Here's the codepen and the code itself of what is happening now. (Click the Portfolio link) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMrgoV

```
<ul class="burger__nav-wrap">
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item"><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_color">Home</a></li>
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_click"><a href="#" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_click-item">Portfolio+</a>
                    <ul class="burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu">
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_big-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="fashion" class="burger__nav-link">Fashion</a></li>
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_small-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="beauty" class="burger__nav-link">Beauty</a></li>
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_small-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="editorial" class="burger__nav-link">Editorial</a></li>
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_small-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="tests" class="burger__nav-link">Tests</a></li>
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_small-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="family" class="burger__nav-link">Family</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item"><a href="blog" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_color">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item"><a href="about" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_color">About</a></li>
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item"><a href="contact" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_color">Contact</a></li>

.burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu {
  display: none;
}

.open-menu {
  display: block;
}

$(function(){
  $(".burger__nav-link_click-item").on("click", function(){
    $(".burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu").toggleClass("open-menu");
  });
});
```

Comment: prevent guessing from our side and try always to create a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: also there's a dozen ways one could interpret your *subtle way* - define what you want. Be specific.

Comment: I hope the edited version is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two states of your sub-menu currently have `display:none` and `display:block`. Since `display` is not *animatable*, you will need to use another attribute to hide your sub-menu. One that can be transitioned.

For example, you could use `max-height`:

```css
.burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}

.open-menu {
  max-height: 90px;
}
```

```js
$(function(){
  $(".burger__nav-link_click-item").on("click", function(){
    $(".burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu").toggleClass("open-menu");
  });
});
```

```css
.burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}

.open-menu {
  max-height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="burger__nav-wrap">
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item"><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_color">Home</a></li>
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_click"><a href="#" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_click-item">Portfolio+</a>
                    <ul class="burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu">
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_big-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="fashion" class="burger__nav-link">Fashion</a></li>
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_small-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="beauty" class="burger__nav-link">Beauty</a></li>
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_small-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="editorial" class="burger__nav-link">Editorial</a></li>
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_small-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="tests" class="burger__nav-link">Tests</a></li>
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_small-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="family" class="burger__nav-link">Family</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item"><a href="blog" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_color">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item"><a href="about" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_color">About</a></li>
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item"><a href="contact" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_color">Contact</a></li>
```

It's a minimal example, but it gives you total control over the duration of the animation (`.4s`), and timing function (`cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1)`) or, eventually, delay (4th parameter, missing here). You can also combine more than one property and you can set the animation details in `transition` property for each of them.

For example, I'll add in some transitions for the `<li>`s, with staggered delays:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".burger__nav-link_click-item").on("click", function(){
    $(".burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu").toggleClass("open-menu");
  });
});
```

```css
.burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  transition-delay: .4s;
}

.open-menu {
  max-height: 90px;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu li {
  transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1) .4s, opacity .2s linear .4s;
  transform: translateX(100px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu li:nth-child(2) { transition-delay:.3s}
.burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu li:nth-child(3) { transition-delay:.2s}
.burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu li:nth-child(4) { transition-delay:.1s}
.burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu li:nth-child(5) { transition-delay:.0s}

.open-menu li {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

.open-menu li:nth-child(2) { transition-delay:.3s}
.open-menu li:nth-child(3) { transition-delay:.4s}
.open-menu li:nth-child(4) { transition-delay:.5s}
.open-menu li:nth-child(5) { transition-delay:.6s}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="burger__nav-wrap">
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item"><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_color">Home</a></li>
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_click"><a href="#" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_click-item">Portfolio+</a>
                    <ul class="burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu">
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_big-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="fashion" class="burger__nav-link">Fashion</a></li>
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_small-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="beauty" class="burger__nav-link">Beauty</a></li>
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_small-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="editorial" class="burger__nav-link">Editorial</a></li>
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_small-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="tests" class="burger__nav-link">Tests</a></li>
                        <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item burger__nav-wrap-item_small-margin burger__nav-wrap-item_hidden"><a href="family" class="burger__nav-link">Family</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item"><a href="blog" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_color">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item"><a href="about" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_color">About</a></li>
                <li class="burger__nav-wrap-item"><a href="contact" class="burger__nav-link burger__nav-link_color">Contact</a></li>
```

While staggered `CSS` animations work well for menus and small collections, they should not be used in more complex scenarios, as they tend to have a few problems:

- they become tedious at fairly low levels of complexity
- many people consider them counter-intuitive
- animations are not chained to one another and if, for example, you want to stagger a looping animation on a collection, after changing tab and coming back you might discover they are no longer synced.

The other option is using `JavasSript`. I've detailed a few aspects in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42261120/1891677), if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `toggleClass("open-menu")` use `toggle()`

The default speed is 400ms and you can change de duration or easing type. Have a look here for all the options: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

If you need the `.open-menu` class to be added then you can use a function callback like so:

```
$(function(){
 $(".burger__nav-link_click-item").on("click", function(){
  $(".burger__nav-wrap_hidden-menu").toggle(500,function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open-menu');
  })
 })
});
```

Comment: Thanks bud! It helped a lot.